# Mass deployment of package to multiple Linux servers across different continents

Tags: ssh, software-installation, package-management, sudo

I'm new to here and want to raise an interesting question about mass remote configuration of Linux servers.

Imagine you get a list of IP addresses for 100 servers with a fresh install of Ubuntu, publicly 
accessible over the Internet, an ssh key already in authorized_keys, and a sudo password for each server. Describe how you would provision those servers and install OpenVPN.

Puppet wasn't installed on those new servers, just got SSHD enabled.

Comment: What do you mean "in max 150 words"? Why would we have a word limit? Don't expect us to just do your homework for you. What do you have so far? Which part of this is confusing you?

Comment: The "In max 150 words," makes this sound a lot like homework or a pre-interview test. Why would we help you with either?

Comment: Sorry to make you annoying, its a local group discussion from my region and im not the writer of question.

Comment: Henrik, just leave it if you feel not comfortable of my question, thank you!

Comment: OK, so what do you have so far? Please have a look at our [help], especially the section on ["How to ask a good question"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We expect users here to at least try before asking. So, please [edit] your question and show us what you have so far and what part of this is giving you trouble. For example, do you know the command needed to install OpenVPN?

Comment: Oh i don't even know have the rules of asking questions in here, because im just helping others...if this question make anyone feeling bad please accept my apologize and i will remove it right now..

Comment: Terdon, you mean apt-get install?! you really asking this or...?

Comment: Don't apologize, you're new here so I am trying to explain how the site works. We're not like traditional forums. And yes, I am asking that. We need to know what you know so that i) we don't give you information you already know and ii) so we can see that you have put some effort into solving this yourself. The general rule here is that if the asker isn't willing to put any effort into the question, then the users here won't be willing to put effort into the answer. So yes, please [edit] your question, and tell us which parts of this you know how to do and which parts are giving you trouble.

Comment: For example: do you know how to ssh into a server? Do you know how to read variables from a file? Do you know how to run a command via ssh on another machine?

Comment: Terdon, many thanks for your kind explanation! I got some experience of Linux but not a daily hands-on guy in front of the console, but always dealing with VMware and wintel stuffs...Usually I will use putty to get into the remote Linux box and excute what I wanted to do, for example, check the /etc and /var/log

Comment: OK, answered this time, but next time please take the time to explain what you have tried and how it failed. Otherwise, your questions will usually just be ignored. I suggest you take the [tour] (very short) and/or read through the [help].

Comment: Thanks Terdon! Why I raise the question in here is because I cannot provide help to my friend, sorry for too straight forward to "ask" question like this, thanks again!

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking, that's what the site is for. All we want is that you _try_ first and _ask_ later.

Comment: Understand, by the way, is this solution have a risk of sending the passwords by the file? Or it's only being processed on the client side (my putty)?

Comment: What do you mean "sending passwords by the file"? The password is sent as a string over ssh, yes. However, the ssh connection is encrypted so it shouldn't be an issue. The password will never appear in any history file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to have a list with the server name/IP and the `sudo` password:

```
server1 pass1
server2 pass2
server3 pass3
...
server100 pass100
```

Then, you can iterate over that file, reading the server and password into variables and using `ssh` to run the remote command on the server:

```
while read server pass; do 
    ssh  "$server" sudo -S apt-get install network-manager-openvpn <<<"$pass"
done < file
```

The `-S` option of `sudo` lets you pass the password from standard input:

```
 -S, --stdin
             Write the prompt to the standard error and read the password
             from the standard input instead of using the terminal device.
             The password must be followed by a newline character.
```

The `<<<` is a bash (and a few other shells) trick called a [here string](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html).